# account activate plus stamp duty charge, is this a legit fee for bank transfers

Tags: scams

A online bank account was set up for with a bank called cornerstone  bank I was told before I could transfer any money or have access to the account that I needed to pay a fee called account activate plus stamp duty charge, it sounds like complete bullshit is this a legit fee or are they trying to scam me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to money.SE! Could you clarify your question? Who set up the bank account for you? Why did you not do it yourself? Have you spoken directly to the bank? Please edit to clarify?

Answer (score 8):

This is a pretty common [advance fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam), there are a lot of questions like this (often times it's referred to as "COT" fee, [see the canonical question here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117921/i-am-asked-to-complete-my-withdrawal-transaction-with-cot-fee-of-1200-dollars?rq=1)).

Fees take different names, but the concept is always the same: someone promises you a tons of money in some fictitious bank noone ever heard of, but you got to pay some fee/tax/commission/insurance and what's not to be able to withdraw it.

There's no money, no bank, and every time you pay whatever they ask for, some other demand will come up for even more money.

Disengage and report to your local law enforcement. Whatever you've already paid them is likely never going to be recovered.